# Find constant term in the expansion of $\left (1+\frac x2 -\frac 2x \right)^4$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Finding the constant term for

$$\left (1+\frac x2 -\frac 2x \right)^4$$

is easy, but that would require converting the expression into a binomial.

However, I have no idea about how to do that.   Completing squares doesn’t work because we have a negative sign on $\frac 2x$.

Comment: Why not just multiply it out?

Comment: @copper.hat The question may be looking for whether there are more efficient or insightful approaches.

Comment: @copper.hat that is obviously not what I wanted

Comment: @J.G. I guess, I don't see any huge clarity in the answers.

Comment: @Aditya No it was not obvious.

Comment: I added a marginally different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you were to use the binomial theorem. Then only terms containing even powers of the factor $x/2-2/x$ would contain any constants because getting a constant would require the exponent of $x/2$ and $2/x$ to be equal. The constant in $(x/2-2/x)^k$ is thus$$\binom k{k/2}(x/2)^{k/2}(-2/x)^{k/2}=(-1)^{k/2}\binom k{k/2}$$ This gets multiplied by $\binom4k$ which is the coefficient from the outer binomial expansion.

Can you sum this for even $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$?

> $\binom40+\binom42(-1)^1\binom21+\binom44(-1)^2\binom42=-5$

Comment: Is that determinant like term just a different way of writing binomial coefficients?

Comment: @Aditya Yeah. it is.

Comment: I am still not able to convert it. Can you write it in terms of $C_r$?

Comment: @Aditya $^nC_r=\binom nr$. Use the `\binom{n}{r}` syntax for mathjax.

Comment: Why are you using $\frac k2$?

Comment: Your expansion is $\sum ^nC_k(x/2-2/x)^k$. Which of these terms generates a constant? We look at thebinomial expansion of $(x/2-2/x)^k$. For generating a constant, $x/2$ and $2/x$ have to have the same exponent. Note that in this binomial expansion, the total degree of any term is equal to $k$. So $k$ must be even, and the constant term is obtained when $x/2$ and $2/x$ have the same exponent i.e. $k/2$.

Comment: Why not use $2k$ instead?

Comment: @Aditya You can either say $\sum_{k\text{ even}}\binom nk(-1)^{k/2}\binom k{k/2}$ or $\sum^{m\le\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom n{2m}(-1)^m\binom {2m}m$. One and the same thing.

Comment: I suppose it will much easier using multinomial theorem. I mean it should be, but I am not able to solve all the variables ie. there aren’t enough equations to solve the three variable equation

Answer (score 1):

Let $[x^k]f(x)$ denote the $x^k$ coefficient in $f$, so $[1]f$ is $f$'s constant term. Then$$\begin{align}[1](1+x/2-2/x)^4&=\tfrac{1}{16}[x^4](x^2+2x-4)^4\\&=\tfrac{1}{384}\left.[(x^2+2x-4)^4]^{(4)}\right|_{x=0}\\&=\tfrac{1}{384}\left.[(y^2-5)^4]^{(4)}\right|_{y=1}\\&=\tfrac{1}{384}\left.[y^8-20y^6+150y^4-o(y^4)]^{(4)}\right|_{y=1}\\&=\tfrac{1}{384}\left.[1680y^4-7200y^2+3600]\right|_{y=1}\\&=\tfrac{1}{384}[1680-7200+3600]\\&=-5.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $a=\frac x2-\frac2x $ into $(a+1)^4 = a^4+4a^3 + 6a^2 +4a +1 $ and note that only the three even terms contain constants, which are their middle coefficients

$$\left( \frac x2-\frac2x\right)^4 \implies 6,\>\>\>\>\>\>\>
6\left( \frac x2-\frac2x\right)^2 \implies -12,\
$$
Thus, the constant is $6-12+1=-5$.

**Edit**:

Same logic, the constant term for the general expression $\left (1+\frac x2 -\frac 2x \right)^{2n}$ is
$$c_{2n} = \sum_{k= 0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom {2n}{2k}\binom {2k}{k}
$$
which yields $c_4=-5$, $c_6= 41$, $c_{12}=3301$, $c_{20}=-1813055$, ... The summation has a close-form, but only in hypergeometric function $c_{2n} = {}_2F_1(1/2-n,-n;1,-4)$.

Comment: How r those terms constant? It still has $(\frac x2)^4 +(\frac 2x)^4$ in it

Comment: @Aditya - the middle term $6$ is the constant; others such as $(\frac x2)^4 $ are ignored

Comment: Fair enough. But your solution still involves a lot of manual work, which wouldn’t be feasible if we were given 100 instead of 4.

Comment: @Aditya - it turns out the result for large powers is quite messy, as seen in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for constant products of four factors taken from $\{1, x/2, -2/x\}$. If you pick one of $x/2$ or $-2/x$ you have to pick the other one as well to cancel $x$. Hence, there's just three ways to form constant products:

- All four factors are $1$, so the product is $1$. There's only one way to achieve this.
- Two factors are $1$ and the other two are $x/2$ and $-2/x$, so the product is $-1$. There are $\binom{4}{2,1,1} = 12$ ways to do this.
- Two factors are $x/2$ and the other two are $-2/x$, so the product is $1$. There are $\binom{4}{2,2} = 6$ ways to do this.

Hence, the sum of all these products is
$$
1 - 12 + 6 = -5.
$$

Comment: @Chrisoph: Very nice approach. (+1)

Comment: What 4 factors are you talking about here? I just don’t understand what you mean by ‘factor’

Comment: @Aditya Expanding a product of four sums, which $(1+x/2-2/x)^4$ is, each resulting summand is a product of four factors: $1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1+ 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot (-2/x) + 1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot(x/2) + \cdots + (-2/x)\cdot (-2/x)\cdot (-2/x)\cdot (-2/x)$.

Answer (score 1):

And Now for Something Completely Different:

Let $f_k= \begin{cases} -2, & k=-1, \\
1,& k=0,\\
{1 \over 2},& k=1,\\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$,

Formally we have $1+{x \over 2}-{2 \over x}  = \sum_k f_k x^k$ and so
the constant term of $(1+{x \over 2}-{2 \over x})^4 $ is found from the convolution
$\sum_{k_1+...+k_4 = 0} f_{k_1} ... f_{k_4}$.

Note that if any of $k_1,...,k_4$ are **not** in $\{-1,0,1\}$ then $f_{k_1} ... f_{k_4} = 0$.

Let $K= \{ (k_1,...,k_4) | k_1+...+k_4 = 0, k_i \in \{-1,0,1\} \}$.

It is not hard to see that the $K$ contains 1 element with no $-1$, $12 = 4 \cdot 3$ elements with exactly one $-1$ and $\binom{4}{2}$ elements with exactly two $-1$s. Computing the product $f_{k_1} ... f_{k_4}$ for each gives
$1 \cdot 1^4 + 12 \cdot (-2 \cdot {1 \over 2}) +6 ((-2)^2 \cdot ({1 \over 2})^2 ) = -5$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $$ p(x)= \left (1+\frac x2 -\frac 2x \right)^4$$ then $$16x^4 p(x) = (2x+x^2-4)^4$$ so you have to find the term in $(2x+x^2-4)^4$ which has $x^4$.

---

> $$(2x+x^2-4)^2  = x^4+4x^3-4x^2-16x+16$$

> \begin{align} (\color{red}{x^4}+\color{blue}{4x^3}-4x^2\color{blue}{-16x}+\color{red}{16})^2 &= ... 2\cdot \color{red}{16x^4} -  2\cdot \color{blue}{64x^4} + (-4x^2)^2 +...\\  &= ...-80x^4+... \end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using the hint of @Aqua :-) we can see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( 1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{4}&=&\left(\frac{x^{2}}{2x}+\frac{2x}{2x}-\frac{4}{2x} \right)^{4}\\
&=&\left(\frac{x^{2}+2x-4}{2x} \right)^{4}\\
&=&\frac{(x^{2}+2x-4)^{4}}{16x^{4}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, since that
$$16x^{4}p(x)=(x^{2}+2x-4)^{4}$$
but since that $$(x^{2}+2x-4)^{4}=x^{8}+8x^{7}+8x^{6}-64x^{5}-80x^{4}+256x^{3}+128x^{2}-512x+256$$
so, we have
$$\mathbf{constant}\left( 1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{4}=\boxed{-5}$$

Answer (score 0):

The combinatorial approach from @Christoph is elegant and efficient. Here we do it the same way using just a slightly different notation. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a series. We also use consequently *[multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)* which is convenient in the current situation.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^0]}&\color{blue}{\left(1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{2}{x}\right)^4}\\
> &=\binom{4}{4,0,0}1^4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^0\left(-2\right)^0+\binom{4}{2,1,1}1^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^1(-2 )^1
> +\binom{4}{0,2,2}1^0\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2(-2)^2\\
> &=\frac{4!}{4!0!0!}\,1\cdot 1\cdot 1+\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}\,1\cdot\frac{1}{2}(-2)+\frac{4!}{0!2!2!}\,1\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot4\\
> &=1-12+6\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-5}
> \end{align*}